# how to verified LDAP on Linux machine

Tags: linux, ldap, active-directory, domain

I want to test the LDAP connectivity between my linux machine to the windows domain controler , so I installed successfully the tool- **ldapsearch**

The Linux machine do authentication of users agaisnt the domain controller ( win machine )

so to test the LDAP I run this command

```
 ldapsearch -x -h domainController.apple.com -b "dc=apple,dc=com"
```

what I get is that:

```
 # extended LDIF
 #
 # LDAPv3
 # base <dc=apple,dc=com> with scope subtree
 # filter: (objectclass=*)
 # requesting: ALL
 #

 # search result
 search: 2
 result: 1 Operations error
 text: 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this ope
 ration a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece

 # numResponses: 1
```

can someone help me to understand the results here from ldapsearch tool?

or maybe the syntax in the command ldapsearch isnt right ?

the **ldap.conf** as defined in my linux machine:

```
more /etc/ldap.conf

logdir /var/log/ldap
debug 0
referrals no
deref never
nss_getgrent_skipmembers yes

host domainController.apple.com
base DC=apple,DC=com
uri ldap://domainController.apple.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, you need to authenticate yourself and get bound to some appropriate object in DIT (Directory Information Tree) which is authorized to perform your search.

Details depend heavily on your DIT structure and DC configuration and DIT structure, but you are using simple authentication (`-x`), so you might be able to do a simple bind as follows:

```
ldapsearch -x -h domainController.apple.com -b "dc=apple,dc=com" -D "uid=you,ou=People,dc=apple,dc=com" -W
```

where `-D` to specify an object to bind, `-W` to prompt for bind password.  `uid=you,ou=People,dc=apple,dc=com` must be authorized for accessing other objects.

Comment: thx , but what is the ou=People ? ( what need to set here ? )

Comment: I guess uid is the  unix ID as example - 63633?

Comment: That DN `uid=you,ou=People,...` is just an example, you need to find your own in your AD server.  DIT structure like `uid=yaegashi,ou=People` is mapped to user accounts and very common in the unix world.  You absolutely have different structure with AD, so look into the content in your own server.